# Issue trying to find length of sequence in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables, methods

I'm trying to find the length of the sequence in an array, between the first and the second occurance of a specified number.

For Example: `lengthOfSequence([0, -3, 7, 4, 0, 3, 7, 9], 7)` would return 5, because there are 5 indices between the *first* and *second* occurrence of the number 7.

I feel like the code that I have written should work, but after console logging it looks as if my `arr.push()` method is only pushing the first index to my indexes array variable, and its pushing it twice. Why would this be happening?

Here is my code for context:

```
var lengthOfSequence = function (arr, n) {

  var indexes = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === n) {
      indexes.push(arr.indexOf(arr[i]));
    }
  }

  return arr.indexOf(indexes[1]) - arr.indexOf(indexes[0]);

}
```

So, for example, if I use my array that I used earlier `lengthOfSequence([0, -3, 7, 4, 0, 3, 7, 9], 7)`, my for loop would find the first occurrence of 7 (index 2) and push it to my index array variable, but it would just do it twice. So my indexes array would just be `[2,2]`. Why would it not be `[2,6]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indexOf` does not do what you think it does. It returns the index of the *first* item that it finds with the provided value. For both values in the array, it returns that first index.

Since you want the index only and you are already iterating over it with your loop, you can simply use `i` itself:

```
indexes.push(i);
```

Comment: also need to break when second is found....if there are more of same will give incorrect output

Comment: @charlietfl: well not really. OP's code does not need a break; but it will always return the distance between the first two occurrences. For more than 2, you could use the length of the returned array and subtract the last item from the first. (Technically it will then even be correct when only one occurence is found, but an error will be thrown when none is.)

Comment: yeah..that's true...array would just grow and first 2 elements are all that is needed

Comment: Thank you! Must have been overthinking it.

Answer (score 1):

You may do it as follows but don't know why it is 5 that you want. I guess it should be 4. OK lets make it 5.

```js
function lengthOfSequence(a,f){
  var fi = a.indexOf(f);
  return a.slice(fi)
          .indexOf(f)+(2*fi+1);
}

var a = [0, -3, 7, 4, 0, 3, 7, 9],
    f = 7;
console.log(lengthOfSequence(a,f));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use just the index and return the difference between the last element of indices and the first one plus one.

```js
var lengthOfSequence = function(arr, n) {
    var indexes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === n) {
          indexes.push(i);
        }
    }
    return indexes[indexes.length - 1] - indexes[0] + 1;
}

console.log(lengthOfSequence([0, -3, 7, 4, 0, 3, 7, 9], 7));  // 5
console.log(lengthOfSequence([0, -3, 7, 4, 0, 3, 7, 9], -3)); // 1
```